# How does the data rate of a CAN bus affect the value of the capacitor used in a split termination scheme?

Tags: communication, can, low-pass, termination

I'm helping to redesign the CAN bus of an electric car, and we're interested in achieving higher data rates of up to 8 Mbit/s. We have a transceiver selected, a CMC to reduce inductively coupled noise, and we are now looking at termination schemes as the next step.

We came across the split termination scheme which, according to section 4.5.2 of [this TI document](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slla270/slla270.pdf) and various other sources, can help stabilize the common-mode bus voltage and filter out high frequency noise. A typical value for the center tap capacitor is listed as 4.7 nF for a data rate of 1 Mbit/s if I'm understanding correctly. Is the relationship as simple as solving for the capacitance with the given equation? If so a value of 620 pF would be suitable for 8 Mbit/s, but the common-mode voltage itself shouldn't be changing at such a high frequency should it? Would this value work?

Comment: "the common-mode voltage itself shouldn't be changing at such a high frequency should it?" There is no way to know without measuring your environment. It depends entirely on what equipment is operating nearby. That's why Figure 10 of your linked document set f as a variable. It's up to you to decide what's necessary and appropriate.

Comment: 8 Mbit/s? How long are those cables in the electric car? Extrapolating, the maximum for the total length (sum of all segments) is 7.8 meter.

Comment: It's a small race car, so the cable length shouldn't be an issue

Comment: Tell me the car model so I could steer clear of it. Even with high tolerance of CAN bus you'll be looking at more error frames than actual data, IMHO.

Comment: @Maple It's more like a one of a kind engineering project than a production vehicle. Your opinion isn't lost on me though. Some of the leads of the project are interested in the higher data rates although I'm not sure we'll actually run at them without putting significant effort down the line in our wiring harness and board routing. Regardless, I think the thought process is if the system is engineered to run at such a high speed then it should have no problems at lower ones.

Comment: Following the same thought process, if the system (CAN bus) is _not_ designed for such a high speed then it _should not_ be used at all. If it is one of a kind project, why don't you use fiber optics? 100Gbps and zero interference :)

Comment: Actually, you don't even need that. Standard off-the-shelf TOSLINK transceivers support up to 250 Mbps full-duplex. And the cables are cheap as dirt.

Comment: @Maple Good point. We still have to build with certain standards and on a timeline however; a lot of the groundwork has already been laid in terms of system architecture and changing communication protocols/hardware very drastically runs the risk of the delaying the project. Additionally, the car not only has to perform on the track but is be judged for its design, and fiber optics may be overkill. That said, 8 Mbit/s might be overkill too.

Comment: Ah, that's where the modular design comes into play. You can keep CAN protocol and controller hardware and design a tiny bulletproof TOSLINK adapter to be used instead of CAN transceiver. Replacing it with standard CAN wiring would be a matter of reconnecting two wires, so you'd always have backup plan. The parts (like TOTX1350) actually cost under $20. You'll be way under budget.